# Can't connect Google DataStudio and MySQL 8

Tags: authentication, looker-studio, mysql-8.0

Google Data Studio Connector MySQL doesn't work with MySQL 8.0 version. It seen to be an authentication problem.

My MySQL Version: 8.0.17
Linux Ubuntu

I have tried all 3 types of password Authentication Type: Standard, Casching_sha2_password and SHA256 password. 
All firewall are inbound rules open. 
The mysql user has wildcard %.

I expect that connect to the database, maybe tring to change any authentication configuration at the server to work like version 5.

Error message: "Não foi possível fazer a conexão ao banco de dados. Verifique seus parâmetros de conexão. Saiba mais sobre conectores de banco de dados aqui.

Código do erro: 1d3f4578" - Sorry about the portuguese. It's a generic not connection error.

I tried to use in my.cnf:

[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

Tks.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that Google Data Studio has problems connecting to MySQL 8.
Please see the following thread on Data Studio Help forums: https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/4115506?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I also confirm Mysql 8 is not compatible: see another issue here:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/70033771?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, as of the [29 Apr 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#apr-29-2021), Google Data Studio supports [MySQL 8](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031):

> **MySQL 8 support**
> You can now visualize data from MySQL 8 using Data Studio.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround here (copy & paste below)

https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/4115506?hl=en

---

I've just resolved the issue using ProxySQL (https://github.com/sysown/proxysql). It supports rewriting queries on the fly. Using that feature you can replace the unsupported global variables with null and then forward the query to your database, making both your database and Google Data Studio happy.

Here's a how to for your convenience.

After installation, before you start the service, edit /etc/proxysql.cnf as follows:

Section admin_variables:
Set admin password in admin_credentials variable.
It supports both plain text (eww) or hashed password (output from PASSWORD() function in MySQL). I suggest using the hashed password. The password function is not available in MySQL 8 anymore, but you can use this SELECT to generate the hash of your password:

```
SELECT CONCAT("*", UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('your_password'))))) AS password;
```

I've changed ​mysql_ifaces​ to 127.0.0.1 as I prefer rather restrictive policy.
Section mysql_variables:

- Set ​default_schema​ to match schema we use
- Set ​server_version​ to our MySQL server's version
- Here you need to keep the interfaces open to public so the GDS can connect to it. However you can update the port it listens on (default is 6033).

Section mysql_servers:

Uncomment first section (except of max_replication_lag), fill in DB server's IP and port

Section mysql_users:

- Uncomment first section, fill in your GDS user credentials. Again it supports both plain test and hashed format of password, use the hashed one.

Section mysql_query_rules:

This is the part doing the magic for us.
Use following rules to replace unsupported global variables with null.

```
{
    rule_id=1
    active=1
    match_pattern="\@\@query_cache_size"
    replace_pattern="null"
    apply=0
},
{
    rule_id=2
    active=1
    match_pattern="\@\@query_cache_type"
    replace_pattern="null"
    apply=0
},
{
    rule_id=3
    active=1
    match_pattern="\@\@tx_isolation"
    replace_pattern="null"
    apply=0
},
```

Save the file. And start the service (e.g. systemctl start proxysql).

Open port 6033 (or any other you've set in the mysql_variables.interfaces) to the public in your firewall.

Update your connection in Google Data Studio to use this port.

And you should be up and running.